# How to make a direct connection in DotNet?

Tags: c#, .net

I will develope a programm that:

- connect 2 PCs
- 1 will be server, 1 will be client
- Language C#.net 2.0
- like a chat

Con somepne give me a start-howto or something I can read, how I can connect 2 PCs aand send text messages to each other?

I will not use .Net 3.5, of severeal reasons.

Comment: How are the two computers to be connected to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html) article provides chat development tutorial using c#.

Answer (score 2):

Read up - lowest level - how SOCKETS and TCP works.

Next one would be getting into WCF which is a higher abstraction level. I would use WCF here.

Comment: You'll get a lot of frowns from the whippersnappers around here who don't start at the bottom and work up anymore, but I agree with you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a limitation of .net 2.0 you can have a look at the [TCP Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) . If not, you could bump up to .NET 3.5 and use WCF.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a WCF service on the server. It will let you keep out of some of the details of lower level network programming with sockets. See for example this [WCF .Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

If you want to learn "real" network programming you should look into using TCP or UDP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I think XMPP/Jabber will do exactly what you want. Take a look at [jabber.net and the examples](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/). Jabber requires a federated server for instance gmail/google and many others or you can host your own. I had good luck with the open source and free [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

Another possibility for direction connection is [Skype via its skype4com.dll](https://developer.skype.com/Docs/Skype4COM/Example).